# How to get selected items from a GridView

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am making a library management software. This is the XAML:

```
<CommandBar Grid.Row="0">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" 
                      Label="New Book"
                      Click="NewBook_Click"/>

        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete"
                      Label="Remove a Book"
                      Click="DeleteBook_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>

    <GridView x:Name="AllBooks_GridView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Books, Mode=OneWay}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
              Grid.Row="1"
              SelectionMode="Multiple">

        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Book">

                <StackPanel Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{x:Bind Path=CoverImageLocation, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" 
                                       Text="{x:Bind Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" 
                                       Text="{x:Bind Path=Author, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                       Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" 
                                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" 
                                   Text="{x:Bind Path=Quantity, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"                                        
                                   Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    </GridView>
```

I want to select multiple bar and delete them when the second app bar button is pressed. This is the DeleteBook_Click function:

```
private void DeleteBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var books = AllBooks_GridView.SelectedItems;

   foreach (var b in books)
   {
      var book = b as Book;

      DataAccess.DeleteBook(book.Title);
      ViewModel.Books.Remove(book);
   }
}
```

This is the screenshot of my app:

[image]

When I click the delete icon, only the first book is deleted. Although both of them are selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `foreach` loop run twice? Does the `SelectedItems` collection contain two entries? Could you put a breakpoint inside the method and step through the code? My suspicion is that when you remove the book from the `Books` collection, the data binding causes a reload and `SelectedItems` change. Although I would expect that to cause an exception in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Also, Activate Windows ;-)

Comment: @MartinZikmund i have just debugged the code, and interestingly it does not raise a typical "collection being modified while iterated thru" exception, it just continue to work on the already changed collection. So if you have a collection of 8 books (all selected), a click will remove 4 books out and the remaining 4 books are still selected.

Comment: @MartinZikmund, I wish I could. The problem is I belong to a middle class Indian family. My laptop costed me 30k in the native currency. And in India the price of Win 10 pro is 15k. I cannot afford that. :(

Comment: Also, I am a student. When I earn my own money, I will build my PC with a legitimate Win 10 @MartinZikmund

Comment: @Hemil , understood :-) . Fingers crossed, hope you can make some money building apps :-) ! Also - check if you have Microsoft Student Partner program in India - if you become a member, you will get free licenses including Windows 10 for free, if you are a passionate developer and love sharing your knowledge :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove a book from the `Books` collection, `ObservableCollection` will notify the data binding about the change which will, in turn, modify the `SelectedItems` collection.

Usually, this throws an exception but in this case, doesn't as it gets "masked" by the fact that removing the first item just moves the second item in its place (lowering the size of the collection) and enumerating forward just checks if the next index exists, and because it does not, the loop doesn't continue. You can confirm this by selecting **three items** - the first one will get deleted, the second one will get skipped, but third will be deleted again.

The simplest solution is to make sure to iterate over a different collection than the `SelectedItems` property. The cheapest way to achieve that is to use the LINQ `ToArray` extension on the first line.

```cs
var books = AllBooks_GridView.SelectedItems.ToArray();
```

This will create a new array which contains all the books that were selected and when you then remove from `ViewModel.Books` and it updates `SelectedItems`, it will no longer matter, as our `books` variable is a **different** instance.

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the collection while you iterating through its items.

`AllBooks_GridView.SelectedItems` is the collection, and when you are iterating through it in the `foreach` loop, you change it by calling

```
ViewModel.Books.Remove(book);
```

After this call, the `GridView` is refreshed to reflect the change you make to the `ViewModel`, and the items in the `SelectedItems` collection becomes less. And in the next iteration, the `SelectedItems` no longer contains two books as you may have expected, it contains only one. And since the code is trying to remove the 2nd book from the collection in the next iteration, so nothing happens and the loop terminates.

Here is a fix:

```
//Now the books collection is no longer bound to the SelecteItems of the GridView, 
//it is 'immutable' in the foreach loop
List<Book> books = new List<Book>(); 
foreach (var item in AllBooks_GridView.SelectedItems)
    books.Add(item as Book); 

foreach (var book in books)
{
   DataAccess.DeleteBook(book.Title);
   ViewModel.Books.Remove(book);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is given in [Kennyzx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815938/kennyzx)'s answer.

To make it work correctly, do something like this:

```
private void DeleteBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var books = AllBooks_GridView.SelectedItems.ToList(); // this will create a new list

   foreach (var b in books)
   {
      var book = b as Book;

      DataAccess.DeleteBook(book.Title);
      ViewModel.Books.Remove(book);
   }
}
```